# Re-sizing selection in Photoshop CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs5

How do I resize a selection once the selection is made? Lets take this example: I take my marquee tool and make a selection but I did not make it large enough. I can re-draw the selection and hope I get it right that time but I believe there is a way to resize the selection by holding down shortcut keys yet I cannot figure this out. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, as there are many selection tools and ways of making selections. But if you are using the `Marquee` tools, you can use the `SHIFT`, `ALT` and `CTRL` keys (`Option` and `Command` on the Mac) to change the behaviour of the tools (and any other for that matter).  I cannot remember which one is which at the moment, but one will put a minus sign on the cursor, to remove from the selection, and the plus sign will do the opposite.  You can also use the buttons on the top toolbar to change modes, but using the keyboard is better.

You can also manipulation the selection using the `Transform Selection` and `Free Transform` options in the Edit menu (might be Selection menu?).  I think this may be what you are looking for, but describing how to use them is a bit difficult using words.  It's best for you to play around with it, or look for illustrated guides or video tutorials on the web.

Comment: oooh, 10k, congratulations! :)

Comment: @slhck: Haha, thanks.  I'm not sure if I am going to make very much use of these moderator tools though.

Comment: Well, you certainly don't have to, just felt like saying "wooo"!